# Conditional click action prevention

Tags: jquery

There is a `<select>` in my page that has some items, one of those items is "**select...**", the default one, with **-1** value. There is also a button in the page that shows a modal window when user clicks on it. I want to prevent the modal window from being opened if `<select>`'s selected value is **-1**.

This works first time. When the user changes the selected item and click `#triger` it opens the modal window but when the selected item is changed to default and `#trigger` is being clicked it shows the modal window again.

```
$("#triger").on("click", function () {
    if ($("#ContactorDropDownList").val().toString() == "-1") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note: I'm using [UIKit](http://www.getuikit.com/) framework.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/rLQDK/37/

Comment: Trace the value of the dropdownlist in your console, what value does it have when the modal appears again? That would likely put you on the right track to what is going wrong.

Comment: I've traced it and it's -1.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your markup? The `select`, the `trigger` button, etc. (PS you have this spelled two different ways trigger/triger).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually show/hide the popup by first removing the data attribute:

```
<a href="#details" id="triger"><i class="uk-icon-plus-square"></i></a>
```

and having your js like this:

```
$("#triger").on("click", function () {
    if ($("#ContactorDropDownList").val().toString() == "-1") {
        return false;
    }

    var modal = new $.UIkit.modal.Modal("#details");
    if (modal.isActive()) {
        modal.hide();
    } else {
        modal.show();
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLQDK/38/).